# How do I take sheets from one workbook and put them into another using OpenXML?

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc, export-to-excel

I am working on a project where I need to merge the worksheets of two Excel files, both represented as byte arrays, using the OpenXML SDK in C#. Specifically, I have two byte arrays, `Array1` and `Array2`, which are the result of Excel file generation.

#### Objectives

1. Open the first Excel file from `Array1` using OpenXML SDK.
2. Open the second Excel file from `Array2` using OpenXML SDK.
3. Clone all worksheets from the second workbook and append them to the first workbook.
4. Save the changes and return the updated Excel file as a byte array.

```cs
public byte[] GetBytes()
{

    var Array1 = ....ToArray();

    var Array2 = ....ToArray();

    using (MemoryStream firstStream = new MemoryStream(Array1))
    using (MemoryStream secondStream = new MemoryStream(Array2))
    using (SpreadsheetDocument firstDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(firstStream, true))
    using (SpreadsheetDocument secondDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(secondStream, false))
    {
workbook
        foreach (Sheet secondSheet in secondDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.Elements<Sheet>())
        {
            WorksheetPart secondWorksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)secondDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(secondSheet.Id);

            WorksheetPart clonedWorksheetPart = firstDocument.WorkbookPart.AddPart<WorksheetPart>(secondWorksheetPart);


            Sheets sheets = firstDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets;
            Sheet clonedSheet = new Sheet
            {
                Id = firstDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(clonedWorksheetPart),
                SheetId = new UInt32Value((uint)(sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Count() + 1)),
                Name = secondSheet.Name
            };
            sheets.Append(clonedSheet);
        }

        if (firstStream.Capacity < firstStream.Length)
        {
            firstStream.Capacity = (int)firstStream.Length;
        }


        firstDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();

        // Return the updated byte array
        return firstStream.ToArray();
    }

}
```

- Action calling `byte[] GetBytes()`

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Export()
{
    var bytes = _services.GetBytes();

    if (bytes == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var fileStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

    var contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    var fileDownloadName = string.Format("test{0}.xlsx", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));

    fileStream.Position = 0;
    var fsr = new FileStreamResult(fileStream, contentType);
    fsr.FileDownloadName = fileDownloadName;

    return fsr;
}
```

The code I have so far is encountering issues related to memory stream capacity and potential type mismatches. I need assistance in refining the code to ensure it correctly merges the worksheets without memory overflow issues.

#### Update

I've arrived at a potential solution, but I'm encountering an issue. The `MergeExcelWorksheets` method correctly adds sheets from the second workbook (array2) to the first workbook (array1). However, the data in the existing sheets of array1 is missing.

```cs
private byte[] MergeExcelWorksheets(byte[] array1, byte[] array2)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(array1))
    using (MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream(array2))
    using (ExcelPackage package1 = new ExcelPackage(ms1))
    using (ExcelPackage package2 = new ExcelPackage(ms2))
    {
        var workbook1 = package1.Workbook;
        var workbook2 = package2.Workbook;

        foreach (var sourceSheet in workbook2.Worksheets)
        {
            if (!workbook1.Worksheets.Any(sheet => sheet.Name == sourceSheet.Name))
            {
                var clonedSheet = workbook1.Worksheets.Add(sourceSheet.Name, sourceSheet);
            }
        }

        return package1.GetAsByteArray();
    }
}
```